# Deploy an application in exe format

Tags: java, c, cygwin, exe

I have been working on a freeware application named **"Cyberoam Iview"** that has two modules, one written in C and the other in JAVA. Just for you know, this is an online application that requires JDK,PostgreSql database,Apache Server to setup on any host system environment.

I tweaked some changes to the available source-code according to my requirement. After the changes, I want to deploy this application as a one single packaged file, like in **".exe"** format. All it's pre-requisites are required to be bundled in a single **".exe"** format so that when I run that ".exe" file on my system, it installs and setup every application that it requires to run like installing Postgresql, setting up Apache server environment, JDK.

I read many posts and discussions, and thus tried my hands with CYGWIN tool to deploy the application, but failed to do so.

Suggestions are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [JSMooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/). I use this for this purpose. You can create a standalone executeable and it even provides a downloader if no Java is installed.

Comment: This is good. But my query was to deploy an application that has two modules, one written in C and the other in JAVA, that work together in coordination and form a complete application. Is there any available tools that first compiles the code of both modules and then combines them together to form an ".exe" out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have some good experiences with [IzPack installer](http://izpack.org/) and I can highly recommend it. You can check out my short and simple tutorial at [Softwarepassion](http://www.softwarepassion.com/deploy-your-java-application-with-izpack-installer/) website - I guess a bit outdated tho.
You should be able to pack your jars and all external files as a single file

Comment: This is good. But my query was to deploy an application that has two modules, one written in C and the other in JAVA, that work together in coordination and form a complete application. Is there any available tools that first compiles the code of both modules and then combines them together to form an ".exe" out of it.

Comment: Hmnnn, for building you can try maven with 'native plugin' or maybe others and then for packaging you can package the compiled c (libs, object files or anything) as external resources with IzPack, not sure how the structure looks now when not packed, but I think its possible